# using session in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

Im trying to use session in my file called response.php,but I face some problem to do it.

This is table.php(pass some data to response.php):

```
function ajaxAction(action) 
        {   
            data = $("#frm_"+action).serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",  
              url: "response.php",  
              data: data ,
              dataType: "json",       
              success: function(response)  
              {
                $('#'+action+'_model').modal('hide');
                $("#employee_grid").bootgrid('reload');
              }   
            });
        }
```

response.php:

```
<?php

include_once("connection.php");
 session_start();
$db = new dbObj();
$connString =  $db->getConnstring();
$params = $_REQUEST;

    function getRecords($params) {
    // getting total number records without any search
    $tid = $_SESSION['tmid'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cusinfo` where AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID = $tid ";
    $sqlTot .= $sql;
    $sqlRec .= $sql;

    //concatenate search sql if value exist
    if(isset($where) && $where != '') 
    {
        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }
    if ($rp!=-1)
    $sqlRec .= " LIMIT ". $start_from .",".$rp;

    $qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot customer data");
    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch customer data");

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) 
    { 
        $data[] = $row;
    }
$json_data = array(
        "current"       => intval($params['current']), 
        "rowCount"      => 10,          
        "total"         => intval($qtot->num_rows),
        "rows"          => $data   // total data array
        );

    return $json_data;
  }
?>
```

Now the session no working,may I know which code should I change?And how to use session in ajax.Thank for advanced

Comment: where do you use the `getRecords` function

Comment: in your php file, do `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: What did u mean of where i use getRecords?
sorry,may I know where should I put var_dump($_SESSION);?

Comment: this is not about sessions. your data variable is undefined. Check this line `"rows"          => $data   // total data array
`

Comment: But after I remove '$tid = $_SESSION['tmid'];' and 'where AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID = $tid ";'
my code will work properly

Comment: after `session_start()` add this `var_dump($_SESSION);` . also is this `AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID ` your column from your table in database?

Comment: I have added 

    'var_dump($_SESSION);'

 after session_start,but It still not working.The AGENT_CODE_STAFF_ID is a column from my table(cusinfo) in database

Comment: i dont see anything wrong with session but if ['tmid'] is not in session, you will not end up with any results which will then $data to be never created(it is only created in the while loop). Are you sure you set the key 'tmid' previously?

Comment: ya,I set it before in another page.
By the way,thankyou for helping me solve this question

Comment: I dunno is it error occur in this page or another,but I double check just now, the ['tmid'] is on my session,but it cant work on table.php
it work on another page